# sql query sort but display specific values on top

Tags: sql

For example I have a table with names as column1 and date as column2. I want to query where specific names will be on top, and dates will be sorted in descending order.

```
|names|dates|
|a    |2016 |
|b    |2013 |
|c    |2017 |
|d    |2011 |
```

I want to display a table where b and c will be on top, but dates columns will be sorted in desc order and the rest of the names will be displayed as the dates columns is sorted. its like having two groups where values b and c has their dates sorted and the rest by another sorted dates. for example

```
|names|dates|
|b    |2017 |
|c    |2013 |
|a    |2016 |
|d    |2011 |
```

What sql query should I use?

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Try using CASE expression with your ORDER BY clause.
Refer http://www.sqlrelease.com/specific-row-at-the-top-then-sort-the-rest-result-set-in-sql-server for example

Comment: i have tried "case when" but it's good if you care about one column, in this case, 2 columns are getting paid attention. i have searched everywhere. i can't get it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want all `b` and `c` on top sorted by dates then rest, try this:

`ORDER BY (CASE WHEN names = 'b' or names = 'c' THEN '1' else '2' END) ASC, dates desc`

**DEMO**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c6ba6/1

If you want all `b` on top, then all `c` then rest, try this:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN names = 'b' THEN '1' 
WHEN names = 'c' THEN '2' else '3' END) ASC, dates desc
```

**DEMO**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c6ba6/2

Comment: why or? i'm supposed to display all needed values on top.

Comment: I have updated the query. Try and let me know if its working.

Comment: ADDED `ASC` ordering for case

Comment: it work sir thank you. i used just your first example because it's what i only need. thank you.

Comment: Happy to help. :)